# How to select a option button from component to template using angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to select the gender radio button programatically. I am using angular 7. here is my code:
(html)

```
<input #male type="radio" name="gender" (click)="setGender('Male')"> Male
<input #female type="radio" name="gender" (click)="setGender('Female')"> Female
```

I tried using @ViewChild but didn't get any selected property to manipulate.

(ts)

```
@ViewChild('male') male_btn: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('female') female_btn: ElementRef;
setGender(g: any) {
    this.gender = g;
  }
editPerson(person) {
    console.log(person.name);
    this.name_field.nativeElement.value = person.name;
    this.salary_field.nativeElement.value = person.salary;

    if (person.gender === 'Male') {
      //this.male_btn.nativeElement;
    }

    if (person.gender === 'Female') {
      //this.female_btn.nativeElement;
    }

  }
```

Here editPerson function will be executed when edit button is pressed in the view.

What I want is when person.gender value is male then male button in the view will be selected and for female accordingly.

Comment: from where you will get whether gender is male or female?

Comment: I have a Person class. on selection of person object of that class, person.gender gives me the value of gender value.

Comment: Why not you use model?

Comment: check my updated answer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we can do this in a `Angular` way and `jQuery` is do not required to do this. Add `ngModel` And `value` to your `input` tag

```
<input #male type="radio" id="gender" [value]="'Male'" name="gender" [(ngModel)]="personGender" (click)="setGender('Male')"> Male
<input #female type="radio" id="gender" [value]="'Female'" name="gender" [(ngModel)]="personGender" (click)="setGender('Female')"> Female
```

for more info check [here](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel) about ngModel

> add this method in your component

```
personGender :string;
setGender(person) { 
    if (person == 'Male') {
      this.personGender = 'Male';   
    }
    if (person == 'Female') {
      this.personGender = 'Female';   
    }
  }
```

Comment: glad to help you.. :)

Answer (score 3):

use [(ngModel)]="myRadio"  for this like

```
<input type="radio" value="male" [(ngModel)]="myRadio" name="gender" (click)="setGender('Male')" > Male
<input type="radio" value="female" [(ngModel)]="myRadio" name="gender" (click)="setGender('Female')"> Female
```

and define myRadio in your ts file like myRadio:string;

and hence 
you can use this value like

```
editPerson() {

   if (myRadio === 'Male') {
      //this.male_btn.nativeElement;
    }

    if (myRadio === 'Female') {
      //this.female_btn.nativeElement;
    }

  }
```

or else call editPerson on radio change event to get the event and value of the radio button

and, do not use javascript to control DOM elements in Angular, this is against the angular philosophy

Comment: you are setting buttons value, but I want to get the particular gender button selected and another one deselected.

Comment: we can achieve this by just `value` attribute in `input`

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using Jquery(if you are familiar with it).

Modify the HTML as follows,

```
 <input #male type="radio" name="gender" (click)="setGender('Male')" id="male"> Male
 <input #female type="radio" name="gender" (click)="setGender('Female')" id="female"> Female
```

And then,

```
editPerson(person) {
console.log(person.name);
this.name_field.nativeElement.value = person.name;
this.salary_field.nativeElement.value = person.salary;

if (person.gender === 'Male') {
  //this.male_btn.nativeElement;
  $("#male").prop("checked", true);

}

if (person.gender === 'Female') {
  //this.female_btn.nativeElement;
  $("#female").prop("checked", true);
}
```

Hope this is helpful...

Comment: jquery should not be used in angular https://angular.io/guide/architecture-components#data-binding

Comment: is it convenient to use Jquery in angular?

Comment: i will suggest don't use jquery in angular.

Answer (score 1):

```
     You have to use two binding [ngModel] like this :


    <input type="radio" value="male" name="gender" [ngModel]="person.gender" > Male
     <input type="radio" value="female" name="gender" [ngModel]="person.gender" > Female

    Hope this works for you.
you can refer below link as well:
https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-radio-button-and-checkbox-example
```